# Why is there a difference between Fermi levels in metals and metal-oxide semiconductors (MOS)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory, fermi-energy

Why are Fermi levels in metals lower than the Fermi level of $\text{p}$-substrates in [metal-oxide semiconductors (MOS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal%E2%80%93oxide%E2%80%93semiconductor)?  Specifically, why is there a difference of $qV$?

$\hspace{50px}$[image]

Answer (score 1):

The metal gate and the semiconductor, separated by an insulator in the MOS structure, can be each be considered to be a system in thermodynamic equilibrium und thus have a separate electrochemical potential, i.e. Fermi level. When you apply a voltage $V$ between the systems the Fermi levels will be separated energetically by $qV$. When the metal gate and the semiconductor of a MOS structure are short circuited, they constitute a single system with one Fermi level. This corresponds to the Fermi levels being aligned for an applied zero voltage $V=0$.

Comment: Firstly thank you. i did't understand the part that when bi apply bias. Electric field can bend the band but it doesn't change fermi level (as far as i know.). But the metal side fermi level below dropped by qV. Bias voltage can change metal fermi level?

Comment: @NailTosun - When there is a potential  difference between two thermodynamic systems, of which each is in equilibrium (here the gate and the semiconductor bulk), the chemical potentials (Fermi levels) of these systems will differ by $qV$.